# How to get value of textboxes, textareas, and radios in the same way in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I want a function/code which will return the value that the user submitted for the field whose name/id is passed on to it. It shouldn't matter whether the field is a textbox, textarea, radio, or select. For example, the field could be:

```
<input type='radio' name='a_21' value='test' id='a_21_0' />
<input type='radio' name='a_21' value='test2' id='a_21_1' />
```

Or

```
<textarea name="a_21" rows="30" cols="6"></textarea>
```

When I do the call:

```
function getVal('a_21');
```

It should return the selected value.

How can I do this? Will:

```
document.myForm.field.value
```

work for textareas, dropdowns and radios, too?

Comment: Std. answer: Use jQuery.

Comment: Jquery works only with ID. With radios i can't use the same id for every option

Comment: @Click Upvote: actually, you can easily write a jQuery selector that will match on the name attribute, further refine using the :selected pseudoclass, and then pull the value.

Comment: While I concur that jquery will handily solve the problem, I do feel that where the question does not ask for jquery there should be an emphasis on providing an actual javascript solution (which is frankly trivial). "Use jquery" is altogether too ready a mantra on SO. Just my $.02.

Comment: @annakata: yeah, that's why i posted a comment instead of an answer. The solution to problems like this is so trivial when using jQuery that they will always collect one or more answers with this recommendation... Writing a stand-alone function to do this, while easy enough, is tedious (note that Seb's answer has omitted the logic for finding the selected radio button in a group, as well as unifying return values such as would be needed for submitting a form via AJAX).

Comment: @Click Upvote - you wouldn't want to have multiple radio buttons with the same ID anyway (the ID attribute should be unique to 1 element) As per the sample, you can access by NAME which would be the same across all elements.

Comment: The HTML specs really screwed up form inputs didn't they? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
$('[name="a_21"]').val();
```

This will give you the value on of the field with name a_21, so matter what the type of field.

**Note:** The quotes are not needed, but I've gotten in the the practice of adding them because of checkbox arrays:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="2" />
```

I figure it's better to be safe than trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Does 'a_21' need to be in double quotes?

Comment: usually i would downvote a 'use jQuery' answer but this is where it really shines

Comment: @Click Upvote, @Seb: it does not need to be in quotes at all.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is different widgets have different purposes. For example, a `<select>` box with multiple selection available, multiple checkboxes, or even single checkboxes (whose value would be just "on" or "off") wouldn't have a single value, so it's ok for them to behave differently from other widgets.

But if you want to have a single function, you could do something like:

```
function getVal(obj){
  if(obj.value){
    return obj.value;
  }

  if(obj.selectedIndex){
    return obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
  }

  if(obj.checked){
    return obj.checked;
  }

 return null;
}
```